# Search through Stack Overflow job messages

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

It would be great to have a possibility to search through the Stack Overflow Jobs messages (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox).

Currently, it's very inconvenient to find something specific, especially given that you have talked to dozens of companies. The only way to do that currently is to click each message thread, then click each message to expand it and perform a browser search (ctrl+f). But that is very inconvenient, takes a lot of time and is error-prone.